# when i click on submit forms then i got this error

Tags: python-3.x, django, attributeerror

I am getting attribute error in Django in forms, I got stuck after this please help me with this one

my views.py  file

```
tasks=['sleep','drink','code']
class newforms(forms.Form):
    task=forms.CharField(label='new_task',max_length=100)

 
def add(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=newforms(request.method)
        if form.is_valid():
            task=form.cleaned_data['task']
            tasks.append(task)
        else:
            return render(request,'add.html',{
            'form':form
            })

    return render(request,'add.html',{
    'form':newforms()

    })
```

and the error shows

[image: attribute error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `request.POST` as data to the form (or `request.GET`, or another dictionary-like object), and not <s>`request.method`</s>:

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = newforms(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            task = form.cleaned_data['task']
            tasks.append(task)
    else:
        form = newforms()
    return render(request,'add.html',{'form': form})
```

That being said, using a list is *not* a good idea. You here introduce [*global state*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil). This makes the program unpredictable, but furthermore it also means the data is not persistent when you restart the server. If you later use multiple workers, it would mean that one worker has another state than another worker.

Comment: sorry but I am just a newbie just started Django a few days ago .if you could explain to me into simple terns that why we should request. post instead of request. method .it would be a great help

Comment: @vikash: `request.method` is just a string, here `'POST'`, `request.POST` is a `QueryDict`, a dictionary-like object, that contains the data that was in the request.